# I cant seem to remove a window from alt-tab list

Tags: autohotkey

I confirmed this bit of code a few months and set it aside for when I will need it. I need to exclude a program from alt-tab list, for examples sake, I am using notepad:

```
WinSet, ExStyle, ^0x80, notepad
```

Notedpad is still present in alt-tab. I could have sworn this used to work.
Did windows 11 new alt-tab break compatibility? or am I doing it wrong?

Any help would be wonderfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetTimer.htm)  or a [loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Loop.htm) to perform an action, each time a window appears:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, exclude_program_from_alt_tab_list, 200 
Return

exclude_program_from_alt_tab_list: 
    WinSet, ExStyle, 0x80, ahk_class Notepad ; Windows 11
Return
```

Comment: How can we have this working for the default remote desktop program (mstsc)? Replacing `Notepad` with `mstsc` or `mstsc.exe` in your sample didn't work.

Comment: @Ayxan Haqverdili: Try replacing `ahk_class Notepad` by `ahk_exe mstsc.exe`

Comment: That didn't help either.

Comment: @Ayxan Haqverdili: Then the [Style](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinSet.htm#Style) is not allowed to be applied to that window.

Comment: Is there a way to skip the remote desktop form the alt-tab list some other way?

Comment: @Ayxan Haqverdili: Not that I know of. You can ask about it in a new site. Maybe someone else can help then.